# Adding several datasource on same column in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcombobox

I'm working on VB .NET 2008.

Target: Bind dynamic datasource in a cell of a Windows.Forms.DataGridView depending on the selection in previous column. The grid must have 7 columns. If the selection on comboboxcolumn 2 or 4 is done, the datasource of comboboxcolumns 3 and 5 mus change using a query with previous selection as parameter.

In a first try to develop this functionality i've tried to use Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView control. I've created a customized celltemplate with a combobox in order to have different datasource for each cell on the same column. All worked fine but seems to be some kind of bug in RadGridView, because when the combobox is presenting the list, after selection the list continued showing, doesn't dissapears as expected.

Ok, after several days of fight with RadGridView, I give up, and I tried to use same strategy but using Windows.Forms.DataGridView. I've created two classes one inherited from DataGridViewComboboxCell and other from ComboBoxColumn, in order to insert my own combbox or have the chance to have access directly to the combobox values. But the combobox showed is the default combobox not my own combobox.

Anyone knows how can I create a custom comboboxcell but using my own combo, and having access from outside to this combo?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You might be overwhelming the abilities of your controls.  You can always break them out into parent/child or master/detail grids instead of keeping them combined into one.

Comment: Maybe, but it worked on telerik, why not in forms? It's not possible to create custom cells containing any kind of controls? and make them accessible from outside?

Comment: You can try, just might bump into limitations sometimes.  I'd rather not fight the controls, myself.